# R: how to subset duplicate rows of data.frame

Tags: r, subset

```
set.seed(3)
mydata <- data.frame(id = c(1:5),
            score = c(rnorm(5, 0, 1)))
ids <- c(1, 2, 3, 3)
> subset(mydata, id %in% ids)
  id      score
1  1 -0.9619334
2  2 -0.2925257
3  3  0.2587882
```

I have a situation where I would like to subset all rows of `mydata` such that its `id` matches my `ids`. The catch is that my `ids` has the number 3 repeated twice. But it seems that `subset` only extracted the unique rows, I'm guessing due to the operator `%in%`. However, my desired output is

```
> subset(mydata, id %in% ids)
      id      score
    1  1 -0.9619334
    2  2 -0.2925257
    3  3  0.2587882
    4  3  0.2587882
```

I've also tried to use the `==` operator instead. However, that didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Your example data frame does not include duplicate rows. If your `ids` have any relationship to your `mydata` you need to make that clear. They don't have the same length, by what rules do you associate them?

Comment: `mydata` does not have duplicate rows, that's correct. I just want to be able to create a `data.frame` with the rows corresponding to my `ids`. So if my `ids` were `c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)` then my desired `data.frame` should have the first and second rows of `mydata` repeated 3 times each.

Comment: So your `ids` has the same length as `mydata`? If so, could you please edit your question to reflect that

Comment: `mydata` is my original data which only has 5 rows. `ids` is any arbitrary vector of numbers that contain the `id` of the rows I would like to extract from `mydata`. My desired data.frame, let's call it `mydata2`, should have length equal to that of `ids`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `%in%`, try using it's sister function `match()`

```
mydata[match(ids, mydata$id), ]
```

This will return the duplicated IDs.